# TimerTask and Handler for showing the pictures every seconds in android

Tags: android, android-layout, timertask

i need to use `TimerTask` for showing three Picture in `ImageView`.Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startTimer();
    }
    public void startTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();
        initializeTimerTask();
        handler.postDelayed(timerTask, 3000);
    }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                        new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute("http://url/background1.jpg");

                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

}
```

and what is the problem?

just what i need in every three second, Images automatically changed to another picture.

So, what i'm doing wrong with this codes?

Thanks

Comment: The handler will do it on its own.  I don't think you need the timer task.

Comment: i agree to what @KristyWelsh saying one more this all UI related things should happen in main thread.

Comment: alos try to use a viewpager and picasso to load images , will help you get rid of lot of boilerplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              /* do what you need to do */
              new     DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute("http://url/background1.jpg");
              /* and here comes the "trick" */
              handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
           }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

}
```

You also had your ImageView not referenced on the `onCreate` method. That possibly created a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: `private Runnable runnable = new Runnable()` private no allowed on public.thank you btw.it's work now

Comment: @Androidenthusiasts yeah sorry my bad :D. Glad you made it.

Comment: don't worry dude :d thanks anyway, it's working now.